# Symfony2 Accessing route variables

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I know I can access current route name by `$request->get('_route');`.

If my route is defined this way:

```
/*
 * @Route("/get_by_category/{id}", defaults={"id" = 0}, name="get_products_by_category")
 */
```

How can I retrieve the `id` variable from within service?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`$request->attributes->get('id')` does the trick.

Answer (score 17):

You can get all route related parameters from the `Request`

```
$routeParams = $request->attributes->get('_route_params');
$id = $routeParams['id'];
```

Comment: While it didn't work - `$request->attributes->all()` didn't return `_route_params`, it did suggest the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```
/*
* @Route("/get_by_category/{id}", defaults={"id" = 0}, name="get_products_by_category")
*/
public function getProductsAction($id)
{
}
```

The `$id` variable will be available within the controller.

Comment: That is correct, assuming I want to access it from controller. I've edited the question - I wanted to access it from service.

Comment: @acid i think ti would be better to pass the id down into the service call, so that the service does not need to know about request - or where the id comes from at all.

Comment: And that the controller does know about the request data and handles it, as that's what a controller does. If the request data is bad controller should abort to view, not pass stuff down layers that shouldn't care about dealing with requests.

Answer (score 0):

In Symfony 3.4, I just added `function functionName(int $id)` and the variable `$id` has defined in the function scope. My path was `something/{id}`. For multiple parameters `like/{id}/that.{format}` I just added the second parameter to the function: `function functionName(int $id, string $format)`, and both of them are in the scope. Indeed, my `functionName` is a `__invoke` in a class used as controller to the route.